# Excel or Power query function to help derive Github 'Commit counts' per team

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I need help in deriving how many Github code commits per team. Sample test data below.

[image: Sample data view]

Excel data here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VOhG_ryqHP6v-kDDIp2Y8TWaYwl00P-/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=100027511676922435348&rtpof=true&sd=true

I have derived all the other columns in the sample view. Except for the 'Commit count' column in Worksheet: Workspace_Github calendarize.

I need help in deriving the **'Commit count'** based following condition:

1. Whether there is an overlap in 'email id' in Tab 1: Workspace team data & Tab 2: B. Github commits for [Application Id] that are linked to a particular [Team Workspace Name]

Per sample data:

1. Karen's commits should not be counted towards Team Alpha. As Application ID 333333333 + Team Alpha combination does not exists in Worksheet C.
2. Tom's commits should not be counted as Tom is not part of the Team Aplha

I have tried Xlookup, Vlookup, other power query functions. I end of double counting the code commits whch is not desirable.

Expected result with dummy data, is a new derived column 'Commit count' in the pic

Answer (score 1):

Powerquery answer based on Table1 and Table2

Table3:

```
// references Table1 and Table2
let
// all combos of workspace name , application ID
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Table1, {"Team member email ID"}, Table2, {"commit_author_email"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Application ID"}, {"Application ID"}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Table2", {"Application ID", "Team Workspace Name"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Team member Name", "Team member email ID"}),
// create row for each month for all workspacename/application ID combos. Not sure why you'd want this, but here it is
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
// if you want erase all the items above here and use your own table of workspace name, application ID, and month

// count by workspace name, ID, Month
#"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(Table2, {"commit_author_email"}, Table1, {"Team member email ID"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "Table1", {"Team Workspace Name", "Team member Name"}, {"Team Workspace Name", "Team member Name"}),
#"Grouped Rows2" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table3", {"Application ID", "commit date", "Team Workspace Name"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),

//combined
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Custom", {"Team Workspace Name", "Application ID", "Custom"}, #"Grouped Rows2", {"Team Workspace Name", "Application ID", "commit date"}, "Table4", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table4" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Table4", {"Count"}, {"Count"})
in   #"Expanded Table4"
```

Note that comment "Karen commits should  not be counted toward Team Alpha since 333 and Team Alpha combo does not exist" is wrong.  Karen is on Team Alpha, and Karen has Application ID 3333, so there is a combination of Alpha/Karen/3333

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks and appreciate your inputs. 

 1. "Karen commits should not be counted toward Team Alpha since 333 and Team Alpha combo does not exist" is a Correct assumption and desired outcome for my problem. 
2. Consider Table 3 as static table. Team Workspace Name + Application Ids combinations are predefined, static and does not change as a result of Table 2. 
3. Exclusion of Karen & Tom's commits is my desired outcome which I stated in my pic  Table C 'Workspace_Github Calendarize' , Please advise.

Comment: Feel free to apply the techniques demonstrated here to get to your actual desired answer, or not.   I shall not be updating my response.  If you already have a table three then just delete everything before // count by workspace name and use your table instead